Android old/all pre-launch reports are gone
Normally I access my Android pre-launch reports in Google Play Console via "Testing -> Pre-launch reports -> Overview". But now about 1 year later I wanted to access them but all of them are gone. The "Overview" (and "Details") page are all empty. Does anybody have the same issue and knows a solution?
